# $f(x)$ such that $f(x)$ is continuous and $f^{-1}(x)\ne 0$ is continuous for every $x$

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, functions

My friend told me it is impossible to find a function $f(x)$ such that it is continuous and its inverse is non-zero for every $x$ and its inverse is continuous as well. Is this true? If so, how can it be proved?

Comment: A function with what domain and codomain?

Comment: The domain of $f$ contains $0$ if and only it the range of $f^{-1}$ contains $0$.

Comment: I think he assumed real numbers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$f^{-1}$ being zero at some point corresponds to $f(0)$ having a defined value. And clearly, as long as $0$ is in the domain, $f$ has a value there. Continuity is entirely irrelevant.

Comment: But continuity on $\mathbb{R}$ implies that $0$ is in the domain of the function, doesn't it?

Comment: @UraUra Sure, if we say that the function is continuous on $\Bbb R$, then it is implicitly assumed that it is also defined on all of $\Bbb R$. But other than that, continuity is completely irrelevant. The important part is that $0$ is in the domain, and that's it.

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with continuity and everything to do with the function's domain.

If $0 \in \operatorname{Domain}(f)$ then setting $y = f(0)$ we have $f^{-1}(y) = 0$.

If $0 \notin \operatorname{Domain}(f)$ then $f^{-1}(y)$ can never be $0$ because $f^{-1}(y) \in \operatorname{Domain}(f)$. For example define $f : (0,1) \to (0,1)$ by $f(x) = x$. Then $f^{-1}(y) = y \ne 0$ for any $y \in (0,1)$.